# How to use two google api keys simultaneously?

Tags: android, google-api

I wanna use google map and google place
So, I have got map api and place api.

But the tutorial teaches me one api usage.

for example
example-project of google map is

```
<meta-data
   android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
   android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

example-pro ject of google place is

```
<meta-data
   android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
   android:value="@string/google_places_key" />
```

How can I use this two apis simultaneously??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need 1 key, make sure you enable map API and place API at google dev console for your project